# Ipa file size after adding big picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, png, image-optimization

After adding a big picture (1.1 MB) to iPad app bundle, ipa file size changes from 2MB to 4.1MB. Can someone please explain why it happens and is it normal behaviour? I thought Xcode optimizes png files or am I wrong?

Comment: Some times it happens but no issues.Our app size can be more than 1GB for submitting to store. (i Guess reason would be pixels of image)

Comment: I would suggest you to use jpg format images for large size and non-transparent images such as for recurring backgrounds and so on.

Comment: You can also optimize pngs yourself using [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) and/or [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com). If you do this, turn off `Compress PNG Files` in your project's `Build Settings`.